# Предупреждение перед отправкой вопроса с картинками

Tags: предложение, вопросы, новички

Часто можно видеть картину, когда код или ошибка вставляется в виде картинки, не прилагая при этом оных в виде теста => такой вопрос бесполезен, так как не индексируется.

Так вот почему бы куда-нибудь не добавить предупреждение об этом, что понизит градус подобных однообразных ошибок от новичков?

**У меня 2 варианта:**

1. При добавлении картинки написать жирным, что код в виде картинки не есть гуд
2. Если рейтинг юзера меньше N, то при нажатии на кнопку "Задать вопрос" в котором есть кратинка, вывалить предупреждение о том, что если в картинке код или ошибка, то хорошо бы его оформить в виде текста.

Comment: ЕМНИП был какой-то порог для вставки картинок. Поэтому новички часто лепят картинки ссылками на внешние сайты.

Comment: ну или как на enSo выводить предупреждение что код требует описания в NN символов и человек не может задать вопрос пока не "распишит" свою проблему во всей красе) А то потом споры возникают на ровном месте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/919529/%D0%98%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%8B-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0/919542?noredirect=1#comment1516953_919542

Answer (score 1):

- Не любой вопрос требует наличие кода.
- И на добавляемой картинке вовсе не обязательно должен находиться код.

Какой код предложишь добавить в вопрос [Отключить autoindent в VS 2015+](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/763478/178988)?

Answer (score 0):

Как один из вариантов решения, выводить сообщения как на enSO:

> Похоже, ваш пост в основном кодовый; пожалуйста, добавьте еще
>   некоторые детали.

Или

> Этот вопрос не соответствует нашим стандартам качества. Пожалуйста,
>   убедитесь, что он полностью описывает вашу проблему - включая то, что
>   вы уже пробовали - и написана с использованием правильной грамматики.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Потому как вопрос, действительно, не всегда предполагает размещение кода.
Но считаю, что словами или одними лишь картинками, но вопрос должен быть понятен всем остальным. А для этого его нужно подробнее расписать.